# edit linphone library iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, linphone

I'm developing a VoIP app on iOS using the linphone SDK.  I git `linphone` project here (`git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git --recursive`).  I built successfully.  Taking a test call works OK.

But I want to edit some files in linphone, for example `belle-sip`, `linphonecore.c`, `linphonecall.c`, etc... in Xcode.  After I do this I have to make whole linphone SDK (like in README: `make all`, ...) to have Xcode run with the code I've edited.

Is there another way I can update the code in Xcode without rebuilding the whole linphone SDK???

Comment: You should ask here, subscribe first https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/linphone-developers you will get best answers !

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build or compile Linphone from Source.

```
$ cd submodules/build
$ make veryclean
$ make all
```

then, open **linphone.xcodeproj** in linphone-iphone directory. Just build as normal.

See more details here: [Build or Compile Linphone from Source for iPhone and iPad](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/)

Comment: I don't want to rebuild whole linphone SDK.My question is: "Is there another way I can update the code in Xcode without rebuilding the whole linphone SDK???"

Comment: @TungTa did you edited the files in linphone? . I have a warning in linphone video call , AVCaptureConnection setvideominframe and setvideomaxframe is deprecated. This warning comes only in iOS 7, and video call is not working. Have you came across this warning? If you have solution please share it. If editing is possible, may be the can retify this warning.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i did but I haven't came across that warning, I'm working on iOS6. I will note your bug and response you if I have a solution. You can ask here http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/nongnu-linphone-f38647.html

Comment: @TungTa thanks for your reply , after getting the updated code from linphone repository video call works fine in iOS 7. But can't fix with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to reduce time is to compile the linphone, belle-sip into the static library by Xcode.
After that, you only need to link to the library (.a file) to run the Linphone Application project.

This method has two main benefit:

#### 1. It helps you to control the core library better.

2. It helps to reduce the compile time because you only need to re-compile the essential library only.